# techtalk.specflow.dll is missing

Tags: specflow

I have tried to write a few features using Specflow. Unfortunately I couldn't find techtalk.specflow.dll anywhere in the system after installed it through the following URL.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee

Am I missing something? Could you please help?

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Remember that you can answer your own questions. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 14):

The Visual Studio gallery download just installs the Visual Studio Plugin for SpecFlow (project integration, editor support, etc.).

You need to refer SpecFlow also in your testing project through NuGet, which will download the SpecFlow runtime dll as well as the SpecFlow command line tool. See also https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Setup-SpecFlow-Projects

Comment: Hi, your comments were very useful. Thanks.I have actually installed Specflow.Nunit that provided me the required dll. Ref.http://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.NUnit

Comment: If you want to avoid installing NUnit you can simply add to the app.config `<unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />` inside the `<specFlow>` element

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the nuget package was not installing SpecFlow correctly for me via the console.

So, I copied the contents of the package (*\packages\SpecRun.Runner.1.5.2\tools) to
%localappdata%\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\SpecRun.Runner.1.5.2\tools

And then it worked